# How do i augment or override a method that was added to a class , using a Metaclass in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, metaclass

Am trying to use a custom Metaclass to add methods to a class, at the same time i want to be able to override or  augment the method added to the class that was created from the custom Metaclass(just like inheritance). I cant seem to make it work.

````py
def print_func(obj,_str):
    print(_str)
class MetaClazz(type):
    def __new__(meta, classname, supers, classdict):
        classdict["print_func"] = print_func # method i want to add to the class
        return type.__new__(meta, classname, supers, classdict)

class Appset(metaclass=MetaClazz):
    def print_func(self,_str):
        # i want to update or overide the method so that the object made from the class can use updated version
        print("heyyy")
        Appset.print_func(self,_str)
        print("today is Friday")

# Inheritance
class Appset2:
    def print_func(self,_str):
        print(_str)
class Appset22(Appset2):
    def print_func(self,_str):
        print("heyyy")#override worked here
        Appset2.print_func(self,_str)
        print("today is Friday")
t_meta = Appset()
t_meta.print_func("Welcome to message For Metaclass \n")
t_inheritance = Appset22()
t_inheritance.print_func("Welcome to message For Inheritance \n")```
````

Comment: It's not really clear to me why you are trying to use a metaclass for this. The inheritance variant shows a method delegating to a method on the parent class (which should use ``super()``, by the way). Effectively, inheritance ensures there can be two "versions" of a method with the same name (one on the class and super-class each). In the metaclass variant, there is only *one* class that can own *one* method of a given name – "adding" a method via the metaclass means *replacing* any previous method definition of the same name. Metaclasses *are not* inheritance, so why use them like this?

Comment: Just to correct a possible point of confusion: ``Appset.print_func`` is defined *before* ``MetaClazz`` adds ``print_func`` to the ``classdict``. The metaclass updates the class' method, not the other way around.

Comment: I understand they are not the same thing (Metaclasses and Innheritannce), but there should be a construct metaclasses can use to achieve this same notion in inheritance. Method is augmentation or override is not my main reason for using metaclasses, to be clear. I just want to know, if its possible and how?

Comment: Thanks for your last point. think that makes it clearer

Comment: With inheritance, *both* methods exist, as attributes of two different classes. At run time, the MRO determines which one `obj.print_func` actually resolves to. The metaclass, on the other hand, is literally replacing the function defined inside the class statement with the global function. There's nothing to "inherit" anymore.

Comment: Without knowing about your actual use-case, what your example and comments reveal suggests that you should use *both* inheritance and metaclasses. Do whatever metaclass'ish things you need via the mataclass, then define one concrete class using the metaclass – put ``print_func`` on the class, not the metaclass. ``Appset`` would then derive from the class, inheriting both its ``print_func`` and metaclass.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thanks for your contribution, you have been of immense help. @ chepner thanks aswell

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are trying to resolve is the natural working way of inheritance. No need to a metaclass, all  you need is a base class, and you can use the Python `super()` built-in to execute the method in the ancestor classes:

```py
class Base:
    def print_func(self, _str):
        print(_str)

class Appset(Base):
    def print_func(self,_str):
        # i want to update or overide the method so that the object made from the class can use updated version
        print("heyyy")
        super().print_func(_str)
        print("today is Friday")

# Inheritance
class Appset22(Appset2):
    def print_func(self,_str):
        print("heyyy")
        super().print_func(self,_str)
        print("today is Friday")
t_meta = Appset()
t_meta.print_func("Welcome to message For first level inheritance\n")
t_inheritance = Appset22()
t_inheritance.print_func("Welcome to message For second level inheritance \n")
```

While metaclasss can inject new methods in classes, the straightforward way of modifying the namespace, as you did, will just suplant whatever was in the class body with the same name. They can be used for applying a decorator for all methods with a given name, for example - in this case, the decorator will augment the method defined in the class body by wrapping it: code that runs "outside" the method.

Answer (score 0):

Your metaclass is ignoring whatever function named `print_func` is defined in the `class` statement, unconditionally replacing it with the global function `print_func`. When you defined `MetaClazz.__new__`, `print_func` there is just a *name*, and its value is looked up according to normal scoping rules once you create a new class. It is not acting as a "default" method until a `class` statement provides a new one; quite the opposite.

To create a "default" method that an instance of `MetaClazz` can override, do the following:

```
class MetaClazz(type):
    def __new__(meta, classname, supers, classdict):
        if "print_func" not in classdict:
            classdict["print_func"] = print_func
        return type.__new__(meta, classname, supers, classdict)
```

Now the global function will only be added to the class if `classdict` (as defined with a `class` statement) does not already contain an entire for `print_func`.